# How to extend java @Interface with it's param

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In a spring boot application where I have two dataSources,

I need to select the proper dataSource using `@Transactional` annotation with the following parameters:

- String `value` *(required)*
- Boolean `readOnly` *(default: false)*

I want to create an `@interface` so I do not have to type the value (chances a developer make a mistake is motivating the decision)

So this needs to be written in a class :

```
@Transactional("transactionManager2")
```

I have created the following `@interface`:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("transactionManager2")
public @interface TransactionManager2Tx {
}
```

This annotation replace `@Transactional("transactionManager2")` and it is working well.

However, I cannot pass the other parameters. For example, this is not possible:

```
@TransactionManager2Tx(readOnly = true)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See my next update =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generally** - that's not possible to do, because annotation's elements values are defined at compile-time. You can not dynamically pass the values there.

But, in `Spring` there is a tricky annotation type `@AliasFor`.

You can try do the following:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional("transactionManager2")
public @interface TransactionManager2Tx {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Transactional.class, attribute = "readOnly")
    boolean readOnly() default false;

}
```

If it doesn't work, you can always define the two distinct annotations, kind of:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager2", readOnly = true)
public @interface ReadOnlyTransactionManager2Tx {
}

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager2", readOnly = false)
public @interface NonReadOnlyTransactionManager2Tx {
}
```